# IOS - Restoring in-app purchase

Tags: ios, in-app

New to in-app purchases. I'm adding a button that allows user to restore a previously purchased product. When I use this this one first prompts user to buy=>enter logininfo->says already purchased->downloads the product. I don't want user to confirm buy eventhough they are not charged for the same product. I have read about using restoreCompletedTransactions, can someone help me with what I need to replace the below code snippet with. Thanks a ton!

```
- (IBAction) OnAlreadyBtnClick:(id)sender
{
     /* code to get the in-app product id*/
     SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProductIdentifier:strIAP_Name];
     [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
     /* code to download the product */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just replace your code with these two lines

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
```

Answer (score 0):

first this method is called

```
- (void)restoreCompletedTransactions;

- (void)restoreCompletedTransactions {
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
 }

 - (IBAction) OnAlreadyBtnClick:(id)sender
 {
 [[RageIAPHelper sharedInstance] restoreCompletedTransactions];
 }
```